# How to Randomize Columns of a Text File in Linux

Tags: linux, sorting, text

I would like to take a text file and for each line randomize the words/columns. The files could contain millions of rows, so efficiency is important.  I've tried the Google route, but everything I find is related to sorting lines randomly and not the columns.

For example taking a simple file like this (I'll use numbers, but they could be words):

```
111 222 333 444 555
555 666 777 888 999 000
000 333 555 777
```

The output might look the following:

```
222 111 555 444 333
777 555 666 000 999 888
777 333 000 555
```

Comment: What tools are you willing to consider?  This would be fairly straightforward in, say, python.  Also, in the output example, did you mean for the `333` to be repeated and not have `222`?

Comment: yes.  It output should be "222 111 555 444 333" for the first line

Comment: I'd prefer to use commands which come standard with Linux, which do not require the installation of additional programs.  But, if there is a solution that is fairly efficient that uses a language such as Python, the I would be happy.  I'd like to to be able to handle files that are millions of lines long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -MList::Util=shuffle -lne 'print join " ", shuffle split' < input.txt > output.txt
```

- `-l` appends a newline after `print`
- `-n` process the input line by line
- `split` splits the input line on whitespace
- `shuffle` (from [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util)) shuffles the list randomly
- `join " "` creates one string from the list, putting a space between members.